# Set Gradient Color to Status Bar Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, statusbar

I am trying to set `Gradient` Color to status bar in My android application. For Activity, i placed below code in BaseActivity. It is working fine.

```
public void setStatusBarColor()
{
    try
    {
        Window window = getWindow();
     window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Drawable background = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to apply same gradient color to `Fragment`. I have a navigation drawer where i have nearly 8 `fragments`. I would like to apply this gradient color to status bar there. The same above code applied there in `BaseFragment`. It is not affecting any color. But, when i apply single color code, it is working fine. Here is the below code.

```
public void setStatusBarColor()
{
    try
    {
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
    }
}
```

What could be the Issue here? I am not able to apply gradient color to Fragment. But the same code is working fine for Activity.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is must be the part of the activity. You can write this code in activity and call it in the fragment.

```
public void updateStatusBarColor(String color){// Color must be in hexadecimal fromat 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
} }
```

Call this method from your fragment

```
((ActivityName)getActivity()).updateStatusBarColor("#000000")
```

Comment: How can i apply gradient color? As i said earlier, single color is working fine. I am having problem with Gradient Color.

Comment: @Jacky Maybe this link solve your problem https://www.whatsthatlambda.com/android/how-to-gradient-color-toolbar-and-statusbar